# Collision in between "END" and "END IF" in BASIC grammar, using Lark

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, lark-parser

I'm trying to create an LALR parser for BASIC using [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark), and I'm having a hard time fixing a collision between the "END" statement and statements like "END IF". Here's a simplified version of the grammar:

```
%ignore /[ \t\f]+/

program: _nlopt _part_list

_part_list: (stmt | block) _nl _part_list
          |

_nlopt: _nl
      |

_nl: _NEWLINE _nl
   | _NEWLINE

block: if_block

stmt: print_stmt
    | end_stmt

end_stmt: END_KW

if_block: IF_KW expr THEN_KW _nl block_body endif_stmt

endif_stmt: END_KW IF_KW

block_body: _block_body_item block_body
          |

_block_body_item: stmt _nl

print_stmt: PRINT_KW expr

?expr: NUMERIC_LITERAL

_NEWLINE: "\n"
NUMERIC_LITERAL: /[\-+]?\d+(\.\d*)?[!#%&]?/

END_KW: "end"i
IF_KW: "if"i
PRINT_KW: "print"i
THEN_KW: "then"i
```

If I try this grammar with a code like this:

```py
parser = Lark(grammar, start='program', parser='lalr')

prog = r"""
if 1 then
   print 200
end if
"""
t = parser.parse(prog)
print(t.pretty())
```

This is what I get from Lark:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 230, in <module>
    t = parser.parse(prog)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lark/lark.py", line 250, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(text)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lark/parser_frontends.py", line 37, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(token_stream, *[sps] if sps is not NotImplemented else [])
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lark/parsers/lalr_parser.py", line 68, in parse
    for token in stream:
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lark/lexer.py", line 341, in lex
    for x in l.lex(stream, self.root_lexer.newline_types, self.root_lexer.ignore_types):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lark/lexer.py", line 175, in lex
    raise UnexpectedCharacters(stream, line_ctr.char_pos, line_ctr.line, line_ctr.column, allowed=allowed, state=self.state)
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal defined for 'i' at line 4 col 5

end if
    ^

Expecting: ['__IGNORE_0', '_NEWLINE']
```

If I remove the "end_stmt" rule, this will not happen. Is there a way to fix the grammar so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Lark does not warn you about shift-reduce conflicts in the grammar and instead silently resolves them in favor of shifting. Often this leads to a parser that does not parse what you want it to - as is the case here. You can make lark warn you about conflicts like these by passing the `debug = True` flag to `Lark()`. That way you'll see that something's wrong even before finding the problem through tests and you might even get helpful information as to where the problem lies.

With the `debug` option enabled, you'll get a warning that's there's a shift-reduce conflict where an `END_KW` could either mean that the current `block_body` is over or it could be an `end_stmt`. This is a problem because a LALR(1) parser can only look one token ahead, but we'd have to look a second token ahead to see whether there's an `if` after the `end` to correctly decide which option to take.

You can fix this, somewhat hackishly, by turning `end if` into a single token like this:

```
ENDIF_KW: /end[ \t\f]+if/i
```

And then using `ENDIF_KW` instead of `END_KW IF_KW`.

PS: Note that your grammar will work fine without these changes if you use Earley parsing instead of LALR(1).

Comment: I had tried using a post-lexer to combine the END and IF keywords, but then I realized I'll have to do the same thing with END SUB and other such constructs. A bit too hackish for my taste. I actually started using Earley in the beginning, but its non-deterministic behavior (at least in Lark's implementation) in resolving some ambiguities was a huge pain, so Ithought I'd switch to LALR.

Comment: Seems like this is the best that can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same conflict with my basic grammar.  Basic language is LALR(2) or LR(2) because of the END WHILE, END IF, etc.  If you have an LR(2) parser generator you can parse basic.  LRSTAR parser generator can create LR(2) parsers.

Comment: I managed to make this work with the LALR parser, and even without the hack sepp2k suggested. You can take a look at it here: https://github.com/elektito/qpybasic/blob/master/qpybasic.ebnf. I fixed the problem with the `END` command by replacing it with a different token (`END_CMD`) that is generated by a post-lexer whenver and `END` keyword is encountered on its own. This is still very incomplete, but I believe I can add the rest of the constructs and still keep the LALR parser.

Comment: Yes, that will work. I did  something very similar many years ago.